# How do you get vid controls to show up in fullscreen video flash as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, fullscreen

I have been searching and searching for an answer for this. I am building a flash video player with a custom UI, and admittedly I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing. I tried altering a skin, but that always comes out wonky due to whatever coding they use. So I'm altering single video components and putting them in the mc what I want them. It looks great, but the problem is that when video goes to full screen, all of the controls dissappear and I can't figure out how to make them show up. Can anyone help me? How do I get a movie clip to display on top of the video when it goes to full screen in flash AS3?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, maybe you should try to make the video player basically from scratch, not using components. It is actually much easier to customize and control... It is not so hard.

And about the fullscreen... It seems you are using a wrong method. You the **stage** to go fullscreen, NOT the FLV component / video. If you make the component go FS, it might result in disappearing controls (the video is fullscreened without the controls).